# Try this what am I riddle?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I creep in, but hit you hard,
I can be painful or soft like lard.
I take away your sight so you can't see,
Break down your brain and make you pee.

**What am I?**

Comment: As a word of advice when making a bunch of these 'What am I?' riddles, maybe find a way to tie the title into it, so they aren't all just named "this what am I riddle" "try this" "new riddle" etc etc

Comment: There are two fantastic answers in the first 10 minutes, each of which fit pretty much perfectly, and neither is apparently correct.  Y'all know what that means . . . .

Comment: If you can add a couple of more lines(in case all the answers are wrong) will prevent this from being closed as too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is clearly inferior to Silenus's answer, but I'll give it anyway. You might be

> old age.

I creep in, but hit you hard,

> For most of us, it comes along gradually, but its effects can be very severe.

I can be painful or soft like lard.

> It can cause pain (e.g., arthritis) and flabbiness as muscles weaken and fat accumulates.

I take away your sight so you can't see,

> Everyone's eyesight declines with age and some go completely blind.

Break down your brain and make you pee.

> Everyone's brain deteriorates with aging, some devastatingly severely. Some old people, alas, become incontinent.

Comment: Yes, the answer is old age. Congratulations

Comment: Thanks! The approved way to congratulate someone on solving one of your puzzles correctly is to click the little green checkmark you may see to the left of their answer :-).

Comment: sorry, it takes a while to get used to things.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> **ALCOHOL**?

---

I creep in, but hit you hard,

> Drunkenness can creep up on you and then hit you all at once.

I can be painful or soft like lard.

> Hard liquor (for example, whiskey) can be painful to drink. By contrast, "soft" alcohol (for example, beer) is easy.

I take away your sight so you can't see,

> Alcohol can make you blackout.

Break down your brain and make you pee.

> Alcohol kills brain cells and makes you urinate.

Comment: No, but the answer and reasoning is great.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> snow (or rain?)

I creep in, but hit you hard,

> A snowstorm or raincloud can come out of nowhere, but hits you very suddenly

I can be painful or soft like lard.

> Blizzard vs. Light snow or heavy rain vs. light rain

I take away your sight so you can't see,

> A blizzard surrounds you

Break down your brain and make you pee.

> The cold numbs your brain

Comment: No, great reasoning and answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> **Winter Season**

I creep in, but hit you hard,

> Winter approaches slowly. They will hit you hard when it goes below zero degrees

I can be painful or soft like lard.

> Painful for joints. Soft as in snowfall.

I take away your sight so you can't see,

> Fog in winters

Break down your brain and make you pee

> Extreme cold can break down your brain and gives you peeing sensation

Comment: No, but answer is pretty good.